# Avoid displaying "=>" when a field is clipped in org-table?

Tags: org-table

How can I avoid displaying "=>" when a field is clipped in org-table? Those arrows dominate some narrow cells, and I can view the full field in a tool-tip window anyway, so I'd like to get rid of them.

Comment: I only see `=>` when I explicitly set a column width in my org tables. Are you setting the column width?

Comment: @Melioratus, yes, and I'd like to get rid of them even when I limit the column width.

Comment: The latest version of Org Mode (tested in version 9.5) has done away with the arrow and replaced it with an ellipsis that occupies only one character.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the following [stackexchange question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/726/truncate-beginning-of-right-aligned-column-in-org-table) pretty much leads the way to how to fulfill your requirement.

Copy the `org-table-align` command (from org-table.el -> `M-x find-library RET org-table`) to one of your init files. Then delete the following line:

```
(add-text-properties
  (if (>= (string-width (substring x (1- f2) f2)) 2) (1- f2)
    (- f2 2))
  f2
  (list 'display org-narrow-column-arrow)
  x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set `org-narrow-column-arrow` to `""` with `(setq org-narrow-column-arrow "")`.

Comment: That doesn't quite work as the string-width of 2 for `"=>"` is hard-coded in `org-table-align`. If you set that var to `""`, the table alignment will be messed up and what's worse is that if `abcdef` were earlier being displayed as `a=>` (truncation to 3 chars), it will now just show `a`, causing more confusion. Also that var is not intended to be changed by user as it is a `defconst`, not a `defcustom`. It would be useful to request this feature by emailing emacs-orgmode@gnu.org.